# Lapse Function?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, modified-gravity

I have this 5-dimensional metric

\begin{equation}
ds^2= N^2(z)dz^{2} + a^{2}(z) q _{\mu\nu}(x) dx^{\mu} dx^{\nu}  
\end{equation}

I'm trying to understand what is meant by a lapse function. Would $N(z)$ be classed as one or, as it does not depend on time but rather the 5th dimension, is it just another warp factor?